# When a host needs to send packets to another host within the same network

Tags: tcpip, gateway, packet

Does the data still go through the gateway (router), or can the data be sent directly, and therefore the gateway is not used?

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: Depends on the network configuration.  If there's a switch connecting both hosts, then the answer is "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosts within the same subnet *by definition* can reach each other directly, without going through an IP-layer gateway. (If they couldn't do that, then how would they reach the *gateway*?)

On most operating systems, you can look at the routing table, for example:

```
$ ip route
10.147.20.0/24 dev zt1 proto kernel scope link     -- one subnet directly reachable on zt1
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link   -- another directly reachable on wlan0
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlan0 metric 600     -- everything else via gateway
```

Answer (score -1):

Think about it. What is each computer connected to?
If they are connected to the router then they talk to each other via the router.

The router is ALSO a gateway. By definition, a gateway connects 2 different networks using different protocols.

So the problem is in the question. The hardware, known as a router, is only a gateway if a computer is looking for a computer on a different network via the WAN connection. Since the 2 computers are on the same network, it is only functioning as a router communicating on the LAN. So the GATEWAY function of the router does not come into play.

Comment: If I have a building full of desktop workstations, they are all connected to the building power supply. So, then, how do I know that the computers aren't communicating through the power grid? (In fact, this is possible.) If I have two computers next to each other (on the same desk/table) and I put my left one on one and my right hand on another, are they communicating *through me*?

Comment: They're not connected *only* to the router. Most home gateways have an integrated switch linking all the 'LAN' ports at Ethernet layer (along with the Wi-Fi AP internally connected to the same switch), and packets do not reach the router core unless they are sent _to_ the router's MAC. It doesn't matter that these components happen to be in the same plastic box, they still work independently.